# is it possible to hover over element and get then the html element with playwright?

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

```
  const browser = await webkit.launch({ headless: false });
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  page.goto('https://example.com');

  await page.waitForSelector('.selectorClassName');
  await page.hover('a[data-type=linkto]');
```

On the site, i have a link, but the href is only added on hover. Is is possible to activate that state somehow maybe via js in the browser that i can get the href on hover?

Comment: We will have to see the page, can't say this w/o looking at the page. If possible please share it

Answer (score 0):

```
var event = new MouseEvent('mouseover');
a.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Its actually quite simple. You just create an event and dispatch it on the element you want.